# Listing top 10 results with the possibility of duplicate matches

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to list the top 10 results and a corresponding cell to those results.

Sheet 1 (*Customer Summary*): (Row 1 is headings, data starts in row 2)

Column A: Customer # (Unique, no duplicates)

Column B: Customer Name

Column C: Sales by Volume

Column D: Sales by Dollar (Can Duplicate)

.

Sheet 2 (*Data Sources*): Result Display:

A1: 1; B1: Larges Sales By Dollar; C1: Cooresponding Customer # to B1

A2: 2; B2: Second Largest Sales by Dollar; C2: Cooresponding Customer # to B2

A10: 10; B10: 10th Largest Sales by Dollar; C10: Cooresponding Customer # to B10

.

I have completed my Column B Results, but I am having trouble completing the Column C.

I tried offset/match, but if multiple customers tie, for say 5th & 6th place, with the same sales amount, the equation only lists the first customer # it comes to.

*=OFFSET('Customer Summary'!$A$1,MATCH('Data Sources'!B1,'Customer Summary'!D$2:D$999,0),0)*

I tried to use index/small equation suggested by other sites/posts, but it resulting display is the header of column A. Am I missing something here? Please Help.

*{=INDEX('Customer Summary'!$A$1:$Z$999,SMALL(IF(LARGE('Customer Summary'!D$2:D$999,'Data Sources'!$A1)='Data Sources'!B1,ROW('Customer Summary'!D$2:D$999)),ROW('Customer Summary'!1:1))-1,1:1)}*

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use a Pivot Table and Filter for Top 10?

Comment: Use a PivotTable or Microsoft Query